# can dstat sum network and disk activity?

Tags: monitoring

i'm setting up a simple perf log using dstat as a systemd daemon that dumps to a csv file. i got it working but noticed that it only records what appears to be moving averages over the given interval. for instance, if i use it in live mode with a 60s interval and burst some tcp traffic, it starts out with 100k and then decreases over the rest of the interval - looks like a rolling avg of some kind.

is it possible for it to instead do sums or peaks for various counters such disk and tcp?

looks like its plugins are just python, so maybe the solution is to create some modified ones that do summing?